# Training samples without ground truth data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, land-cover, landsat-7

Does anybody have any idea how I could go about verifying my training classes properly in ArcGIS 10.3, WITHOUT ground-data. I am constructing a land cover map for 2011 in Cumbria and so far I have verified very little of the samples I have created.

Any ideas on other sources or methods, other than going out and collecting field dat a myself right now?

I am using a supervised classificaiton approach with land sat 7 imagery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty common approach for validating a medium resolution (such as Landsat) classification is to rely on higher resolution datasets, such as aerial or even VHR satellite data (WorldView, Pleiades etc.).

One option for getting access to such data is to use the built in basemaps in ArcGIS, where aerial photos are available for much of the western hemisphere.

If you choose to use that approach, you should consider the implications of relying on a basemap. Implications such as lack of knowledge of acquisition dates and sampling bias associated with seasonality in the area.